# Transferring Data from old to new laptop for KOrganiser?

Tags: calendar, transfer, korganizer

KOrganizer says simply in its' help file in order to import to choose File>Import>Import Calendar with then the possibility of creating a new calendar or of merging it.
First I did an export from the old laptop and copied the files with a USB drive to the desktop of the new laptop.
On trying to import>Import Calendar on the new laptop I get as far as the desktop but the copies of the exported files (which are there) don't appear. I've had a look in "Files>Computer" in the old laptop to see whether there was a data file which I could copy and paste into the same place on the new laptop but as I don't know enough to touch all that I prefer asking!
Thanks for any help
Garoolgan

Comment: are you sure you are looking in the right folder for the files? how did you copy them from the USB?

Comment: I went to the old laptop and exported the two types (as iCalendar and vCalendar as I didn't know which I would need), I then pasted the  two files on the desktop of the new laptop and went to KOrganizer to import them.

Comment: did you use dolphin? or drag and drop? right click  copy and paste? Use dolphin to verify the location of the files

Comment: I used copy/paste to the USB drive and copy/paste to the new desktop.  Sorry I don't know dolphin. I'll try to find out what it is.

Comment: dolphin is the KDE file manager, you are using KDE desktop yes?

Comment: I have no idea what a KDE desktop is. I now have two laptops with Ubuntu on them and I was using KOrganizer as my agenda in  Ubuntu

Comment: Sorry for the delays in replying . I'm retired but I am the only slightly valid memeber of our household so there are plenty of things to do

Comment: Now I'm off to the supermarket.  I live in France at it is 14H10 here. I am looking forward to your reply on my return and thanks for taking an interest.

Comment: Thanks for the Dolphin, I downloaded it and fiddled a bit and it worked!

Comment: I'm receiving the same information again. Thanks the Dolphin bit worked and just as well as I'll soon be transferring again to yet another laptop.